# Input field is not focusing when clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms

I have an  `<input>` field inside a div that is giving me trouble.

It is inside a div with position `absolute`. When I click on it, it does not get the focus, so I cannot type inside it.
The other parts of an input field work as they should: The cursor changes to the text symbol when over it, I can focus on it using the right-click with the mouse or the `Tab` key and when it DOES get focus I can type on it normally.

I even binded a console log to it when clicked, just to make sure the the correct element being clicked. The log does happen, but it still doesn't get the focus on clicking.

Does anyone have an idea of what may be happening here?

Edit: added more parts of my code, sorry for having such little code before.
Here is my code:

```js
// link that makes the form appear, on another part of the UI
jQuery("#link").on("click", function() {
  jQuery(".form").show()
})

jQuery("#close-button").on("click", function() {
  jQuery(".form").hide()
})
// This was added to test if the click was happening,
// it does not work with or without this
jQuery("#input-field").on("click", function(e) {
  console.log("clicked")
  console.log(e.target) // this is returning the "input-field" element
})
```

```css
.form {
  background-color: #EAE8E8;
  position: absolute;
  width: 99%;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  bottom: 0;
  display: none;
  border: 1px solid;
}

#close-button {
  float: right;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* input-field doesn't have any CSS defined by code yet */
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="link">Click to show form</button>
<div class="form">
  <!-- this has position: absolute -->
  <img src="'/close.png" id="close-button">
  <!-- Here are some other images that can be clicked... that all works fine -->
  <input id="input-field" />
  <!-- this is not getting focused when clicked -->
</div>
```

Comment: This html structure seems to work fine. Is there any JS running there?

Comment: Please share your entire code - you tagged this question [tag:javascript], so there must be some JavaScript interfering with the above, as it would work perfectly normally.

Comment: You need to post all the relevant code (HTML, CSS, JavaScript). Based on what you've said and shown, your issue is not reproduceable.

Comment: Do you have a click handler attached to the DIV?  That may be overriding the click on the input.

Comment: I added the JS code used in that part of the UI, more HTML and the CSS

Comment: @Barmar No, I don't have a click handler on the DIV. I do have one on the input field that I added to help me figure out with it was not focusing on it.

Comment: It seems to work in the snippet here, so there must be something else on your site that's interfering.

Comment: Same here, code working on the snippet. Must be something else that is interfering.

Answer (score 0):

You might add `.focus()` to autofocus your desired input. Here is your example:

```js
jQuery("#link").on("click", function() {
  jQuery(".form").show()
  // Add to auto focus your input
  jQuery("#input-field").focus();
})

jQuery("#close-button").on("click", function() {
  jQuery(".form").hide()
})
```

```css
.form {
  background-color: #EAE8E8;
  position: absolute;
  width: 99%;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  bottom: 0;
  display: none;
  border: 1px solid;
}

#close-button {
  float: right;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="link">Click to show form</button>
<div class="form">
  <img src="'/close.png" id="close-button">
  <input id="input-field" />
</div>
```